# CVXPY won't install: File "setup.py" not found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, conda, cvxpy

When trying to install the CVXPY package through Spyder by using

!pip install cvxpy

It returns ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Wout\anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Wout\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C

and like 30 more lines of errors related to this one

When I try

!pip install -e .  [with the path selected above] it returns

ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: C:\

I already deleted Spyder and reinstalled, I have Vision studio installed and tried it even through Conda but nothing seems to work

Could someone please help or give another method? It would mean the world to me so I could continue my work

Thanks!

Comment: Seems you are using an anacond-based python-distribution. The cvxpy documentation has a chapter about install, which explicitly shows what to do when using anaconda (not pip!)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually also tried it through anaconda as well but not after i reinstalled spyder. I tried again now and it seems to be okay. Have a nice day.